# rails devise use helper in mail view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have a table with a key and value.
I want in my mail view to display the text from my table.

my config/initializers/devise.rb looks like this:

```
[...]
  Devise::Mailer.class_eval do
    helper :mail_settings
  end
end
```

my helpers/mail_settings_helper.rb like this:

```
module MailSettingsHelper
    def get_setting(name)
      @value = MailSettings.where(name: name)
    end
end
```

this combination works great on normal views but in my MaialViewFile O got a error.

my File: app/views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb

```
<%
link = link_to 'Account bestätigen', confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token)
email = get_setting('confirmation_instructions_mail')
mail = email[0].value.gsub('##EMAIL##', @email)
new_mail = mail.gsub('##LINK##', link)
%>
<%= new_mail.html_safe %>
```

and the error:

```
undefined method `get_setting' for #<#<Class:0x7cc4ac0>:0x7cfe2e8>
```

Comment: Have you restarted server?

Comment: @SSR nope, but it work's but why?

Comment: When ever you make any changes to configuration files you need to reload all the configuration settings. so need to restart server. You didn't restart server, still it works?

Comment: i restarted the server and all works fine